# build linux kernel with EXPERT and without DEBUG_KERNEL

Tags: linux, debugging, kernel

is a good idea build the mainline kernel (4.9.y atm) without DEBUG_KERNEL but with EXPERT enabled?
i archieved this by deleting line 1383 from init/Kconfig ("select DEBUG_KERNEL"):

```
> menuconfig EXPERT
> bool "Configure standard kernel features (expert users)"  
> # Unhide debug options, to make the on-by-default options visible     
> select DEBUG_KERNEL <--- *this line*
>   help      
> This option allows certain base
> kernel options and settings
> to be disabled or tweaked. This is for specialized
> environments which can tolerate a "non-standard" kernel.
> Only use this if you really know what you are doing.
```

I think this should reduce overhead but can it cause issues?
why DEBUG_KERNEL is forced here?

Comment: Thanks a lot for saying how you did it. Forcing DEBUG_KERNEL with EXPERT doesn't make a lot of sense, IMHO.